# No transform from baselink to world

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use tum_simulator to map an environment following the example of hector_slam. I added the sensors which are included in hector_slam. And I added the mapping and visualization nodes from hector_slam to tum_simulator launch files. But in rviz, I get the following errors,

Global Status: Fixed Frame [world] does not exist

Robot Model: No transform from [ardrone_base_bottomcam], [ardrone_base_frontcam], [base_link],  [bottom_link], [front_link], [sonar_link] to [world]

Map: No transform from [map] to [world]

Camera: No Image received

tf: No transform from [ardrone_base_bottomcam], [ardrone_base_frontcam], [base_footprint], [base_stabilized], [base_link],  [bottom_link], [front_link],  [nav], [sonar_link] to [world]

How do I solve this problem?

How do I add the missing transform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217687/no-transform-from-baselink-to-world/) by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hector_slam should broadcast the `world -> odom` transform, and the robot's driver (or gazebo in this case) should broadcast `odom -> base_link`, thus providing a chain from world to base_link. The world frame may not show up immediately before hector_slam has received any data. To see what's going on in rviz, change the global frame to something that exists like odom or base_link.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can solve it with static transform, e.g:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 /world /map 100" />
</launch>
```

http://wiki.ros.org/tf

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2015-09-15**:
You should use tf2 not tf.